# I'm trying to use spring security with PostgreSQL, I want get users from database but getting StackOverflowError: null

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"conf"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"application.controller"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"applicaion.model"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"applicaion.dao"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"usersDetails"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Security config part

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();}

}
```

User Entity

"felhasznalonev"==username and "felhasznalo"==user
in hungarian
in the database table has theese names

```
@Entity
@Table( name="felhasznalo")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    
    @Column( unique=true, nullable=false )
    private String felhasznalonev;
    
    @Column( nullable=false )
    private String jelszo;
    
    private int statusz;
    
    public User() {}

    public User(String felhasznalonev,String jelszo,int statusz) {
        this.felhasznalonev=felhasznalonev;
        this.jelszo=jelszo;
        this.statusz=statusz;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFelhasznalonev() {
        return felhasznalonev;
    }

    public void setFelhasznalonev(String email) {
        this.felhasznalonev = email;
    }

    public String getJelszo() {
        return this.jelszo;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.jelszo = password;
    }

    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }

    public int getStatusz() {
        return statusz;
    }

    public void setStatusz(int statusz) {
        this.statusz = statusz;
    }
    
}
```

userServiceimpl part

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService  {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = findByUsername(username);

        return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

UserDetailsImpl part

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public UserDetailsImpl(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    public UserDetailsImpl() {}
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getJelszo();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getFelhasznalonev();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

UserService part

```
public interface UserService {
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
        
    User findByUsername(String username);
    
}
```

When i run the code everything looks fine, the basic login page come in, i enter the username/password from the database but nothing happen

and IntellIj write this:

```
2021-11-25 13:12:48.870 ERROR 13928 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:472) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:472) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
-||-
```

the connection with database is good, i can list users as well
Thanks for reading all this and sorry for bad english and mistakes, have a good day!

Comment: Edit your title because it's look like content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.StackOverflowError` error tell you method declaration in `service` layer is not linked with any `JpaRepository`. Problem is came up from `loadUserByUsername` method in `userServiceimpl`. You declare method `findByUsername` without linked with `Repository`.

**Change**

```
User user = findByUsername(username);
```

**To**

```
User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
```

And `UserServiceImpl` Implements with `UserDetailsService` only. You need to change in`Security config` code because it has more problem like add wrong annotation and two method declare with same name etc...

**Modified `Security config`**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception     {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have doubly declared userDetailsService with the same name,

First:

```
   @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
```

Second:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService  {
```

It may cause the problem. You should have only one instance of userDetailService.

Comment: if i delete the one from the securityconfig.java it doesnt start : Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in usersDetails.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'usersDetails.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: This is another problem of your application. Spring cannot create UserServiceImpl, because does not see UserRepository. Why? Probably its package is not scanned. Please include it in ComponentScan annotation.
3rd problem: Inisde UserServiceImpl you have defined 2x autowired annotation. First above property, second above constructor. You should decide how do you want autowire objects

Comment: (best u can do remove @Autowired from property, and leave at constructor)

Comment: they are in the same package, and removed Autowired, same problem

Answer (score 0):

In your SecurityConfig Can you try removing

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
```

And changing the implementation for

```
 @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

to

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Comment: Same problem: Parameter 0 of constructor in usersDetails.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'usersDetails.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Comment: Updated the answer. Small mistake. You need to inject the UserRepository in userDetailsService.. Just remove the super.userDetailsService() and use the userDetails Service  decleared as attribute